# How do I make a subfigure for each colour so that there are 2 in each row?

Tags: subfloats

So I want to make subfigure inside a subfigure. So 1 for green, 1 for yellow, and 1 for purple. And within each colour have 2 further subfigures.

```
\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Green.png}
         \caption{Green}
         \label{fig}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Green.png}
         \caption{G}
         \label{fig}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Purple.png}
         \caption{P}
         \label{fig}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Purple_split.png}
         \caption{P}
         \label{fig}
         \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Yellow_unsplit.png}
         \caption{Y}
         \label{fig}
         \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Yellow_split.png}
         \caption{Y}
         \label{fig}
         \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
    \caption{Spectral lines}
    \label{fig:photos}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

- Since all images has equal width it is sensible to use `Gin`˙keys for determining of their width (and by this make code shorter)
- I would define image width equal to `subfigure` width and reduce `subfigure` width accordingly, for example to `0.45\textwidth` (or to `0.49\textwidth` if you like to have images slightly bigger)
- between each row with two images you need to insert empty line

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % in real document remove option "demo"
\usepackage[skip=1ex, belowskip=1.5ex]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
         \includegraphics{Green_unsplit.png}
         \caption{Green}
         \label{fig:green-unsplit}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
         \includegraphics{Green_split.png}
         \caption{Green}
         \label{fig:green-split}
     \end{subfigure}

     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics{Purple_unsplit.png}
         \caption{Purple}
         \label{fig:purple-unsplit}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
         \includegraphics{Purple_split.png}
         \caption{Purple split}
         \label{fig:purple-split}
         \end{subfigure}%

     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
         \includegraphics{Yellow_unsplit.png}
         \caption{Yellow }
         \label{fig:yellow-unsplit}
         \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
         \includegraphics{Yellow_split.png}
         \caption{Yellow}
         \label{fig:yellow-split}
      \end{subfigure}

\caption{Spectral line}
\label{fig:photos}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ahhh thanks so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your two images are wider than `\textwidth` because you have a trailing space. Use

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
% customized list environments

\usepackage{subcaption}
% verbatim text, long and colored tables
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Green_unsplit.png}
         \caption{Green}
         \label{fig:green-unsplit}
     \end{subfigure}%
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Green_split.png}
         \caption{Green}
         \label{fig:green-split}
     \end{subfigure}%
\hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{Purple_unsplit.png}
         \caption{Purple}
         \label{fig:purple-unsplit}
     \end{subfigure}%
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{Purple_split.png}
         \caption{Purple split}
         \label{fig:purple-split}
         \end{subfigure}%
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{Yellow_unsplit.png}
         \caption{Yellow }
         \label{fig:yellow-unsplit}
         \end{subfigure}%
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{Yellow_split.png}
         \caption{Yellow}
         \label{fig:yellow-split}
      \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
    \caption{Spectral line}
    \label{fig:photos}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Or use 0.49 instead of 0,5

[image]

Comment: `\allowbreak` would be better.

Comment: @JohnKormylo where would i add the ```\allowbreak```

Comment: Also, adding ```%``` doesn't seem to work :((

Comment: `\end{subfigure}\allowbreak`

Comment: @JohnKormylo: `\allowbreak` doesn't solve the trailing space issue.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `\allowbreak` after each `subfigure`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % in real document remove option "demo"
\usepackage[skip=1ex, belowskip=1.5ex]{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Green.png}
         \caption{Green}
         \label{fig}
     \end{subfigure}\allowbreak
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Green.png}
         \caption{G}
         \label{fig}
     \end{subfigure}\allowbreak
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Purple.png}
         \caption{P}
         \label{fig}
     \end{subfigure}\allowbreak
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Purple_split.png}
         \caption{P}
         \label{fig}
         \end{subfigure}\allowbreak
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Yellow_unsplit.png}
         \caption{Y}
         \label{fig}
         \end{subfigure}\allowbreak
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Yellow_split.png}
         \caption{Y}
         \label{fig}
         \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Spectral lines}% \caption begins and ends with a \par
    \label{fig:photos}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```